# why is my notification channel (External table )null?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns, snowflake-schema, external-tables

I have created a external table in snowflake with data in S3. and automated it with SNS.

I have created S3 integration object with 2 buckets (Bucket1 and BUcket 2).

I have created a SNS topic and subscripted the same topic to both S3 buckets.

when I click on Show external tables I am getting null in notification_channel for the data that is being from bucket 2:

[image]

I am able to do a ls on that path and also able to manually refresh the stage, but is not updating automatically.

What might cause this issue?

Comment: Did you gave auto_refresh=true in external table definition?

Comment: Yes, i have given

Comment: Try this, if not already - https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SHOW-EXTERNAL-TABLES-COMMAND-has-Notification-Channel-value-empty

Comment: Tried it , not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a condition to the topic access policy like below to include all the buckets works

```
 "Action": "SNS:Publish",
//      "Resource": "<sns arn>",
//      "Condition": {
//        "ArnLike": {
//          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:*"
//        }
//      }
```